# Setting array to contain string values results in error

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm new to C++ and not totally sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code. Simple enough

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string WORD_FILE = ("/Users/matt/Desktop/C++/Hangman/Hangman/words.txt");
const int WORDS_USED = 20;

string fillArray(string words[]);

int main() {
    string words[WORDS_USED];

    fillArray(words);


}

string fillArray(string words){
    string word;
    ifstream inputStream;
    inputStream.open(WORD_FILE);
    while (int x=0 < WORDS_USED){
        inputStream >> word;
        words[x] = word;


    }
    return words;
}
```

When I run this, I get an error on the "words[x] = word;" line.

```
Assigning to 'value_type' (aka 'char') from incompatible type 'string'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why it is taking anything as a character

Comment: You should pass `std::string` by reference.

Comment: Why do you declare `int x` inside the conditional expression of the `while` loop?  Try declaring `x` before the `while` loop.

Comment: If you use string, include the header. You're either going to need to fix the return type of your function too, or pass by reference. Reference is better because otherwise you're returning a pointer to a local variable. Consider using a vector as well.

Comment: You don't increment `x` inside the `while` loop, so you are always assigning to `words[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code.

You declared `fillArray()` as accepting an array of `std::string` objects as input, and returning a single `std::string` as output.  But, in your function definition, the input parameter is not declared as an array, it is a single `std::string` instead.  That is why you are getting the compiler error - you really are trying to assign a `std::string` read from the `std:::ifstream` to a single `char`.

Also, the syntax of your `while` loop is all wrong.  But even if it weren't, you are not incrementing `x` at all, so your loop would not break when it reached 20 words.  And you are not doing any error handling on the `ifstream` reading, so the loop would not break when it reaches EOF or encounters a reading error, either.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string WORD_FILE = "/Users/matt/Desktop/C++/Hangman/Hangman/words.txt";
const int WORDS_USED = 20;

int fillArray(string words[]);

int main() {
    string words[WORDS_USED];
    fillArray(words);
    return 0;
}

int fillArray(string words[]) {
    ifstream inputStream(WORD_FILE);
    string word;
    int numWords = 0;
    while ((numWords < WORDS_USED) && (inputStream >> word)) {
        words[numWords] = word;
        ++numWords;
    }
    return numWords;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo in your function definition:

```
string fillArray(string words){
    ...
}
```

`words` should be an array there, i.e. `words[]`. Your compiler should have warned you that the definition signature doesn't match the declaration earlier in the file.